# Basis of Complex vs Real Vector Space

Tags: linear-algebra, change-of-basis

Let $e=\{e_1,e_2,...,e_n\} $ be a basis for the complex vector space X. Is there a general way of finding a basis for X when regarded as a real vector space?

We know that for every x in X there are complex $z_i$ such that: $$ x= \sum_{j=1}^n z_i e_i =(z_1,...,z_n)_e    $$ 
and $z_i$ not all 0.  Intuitively I'd say that when regarded as a real vector space X has dimension $2n$ , so we should use all the $e_i$ plus another n vectors which we'll find from the expression of x, but I can't seem to find how to even start doing it. Perhaps I'm wrong, do correct me :) Thanks in advance.

Edit: Are the vectors of e even linearly independent in the real vector space? Are any linearly independent vectors of the complex vector space, independent in the real one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple-to-find basis is
$$
e_1, i\cdot e_1, e_2, i\cdot e_2,\ldots, i\cdot e_n
$$
And vectors in a complex vector space that are complexly linearly independent, which means that there is no complex linear combination of them that makes $0$, are automatically real-linearly dependent as well, because any real linear combination is a complex linear combination, and we've established that those do not exist.

In fact, we may do the same as above, and take our set of vectors, duplicate it, multiply each element in the duplicate by $i$, and we will have a twice as large, real-linearly independent set.

Comment: Not only is this basis easy to construct, this construction from real bases to complex bases is actually canonical. (And +1, btw.)

Comment: @Travis: Does "canonical" have a technical meaning here?

Comment: @HenningMakholm Other than splitting each vector into two, I don't think so. A better word, at least if this were a common thing to do, would perhaps be "standard". That being said, isn't $i$ (at least up to sign) somewhat canonical over $\Bbb R$?

Comment: @HenningMakholm By canonical I just mean that the operation $(e_a) \mapsto (e_1, i e_1, \ldots, e_n, i e_n)$ is basis-independent. Of course, so the operation given by replacing $i$ in that formula by $\exp\left(\frac{\pi i}{3}\right)$, so "standard" is perhaps the better word, as the construction in the answer is what people actually do in practice.